# Custom Overlapping UITableViewCells

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

UITableCells that I want need to be overlapping each other. Thats something I was never able to acheive , right now to get this effect , i am adding this as a subview on scrollview. [image]

Would really like if someone have better solution for this .

Comment: Can you show the original screenshot of what you have done so far?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure the cells have their `clipsToBounds` properties set to `NO`. Also, if the order is such that a cell needs to overlap the preceeding one, make sure that the cells' `layer`'s `zPosition` property increase with the item index. Meaning that in your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method, you would need to do something along the line of :

```
cell.layer.zPosition = indexPath.section * 1000 + indexPath.item;
cell.clipsToBounds = NO;
```

If the overlapping needs to be the other way around, multiply the `zPosition` by `-1`. Note the above implies you won't have more than 1000 items in a section, which you can adjust to fit your needs.

Finally, you might want to look into [UICollectionView](http://nshipster.com/uicollectionview/), which provides a lot more visual flexibility than UITableView, and can be seen as a sort of generalization of the latter.